# Remove emoticons and characters using python

Tags: python, twitter, twython

I need to scrape data from twitter and get the output in arabic language. 
I used this code:

```
    # -*- coding: cp1256 -*-
from twython import Twython, TwythonError
import re

APP_KEY="my appkey"
APP_SECRET="my app secret key "
OAUTH_TOKEN="app outh token"
OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET="app outh token secret "

# Requires Authentication as of Twitter API v1.1
twitter = Twython(APP_KEY, APP_SECRET, OAUTH_TOKEN, OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET)
try:
    search_results = twitter.search(q='الاعلام', lang='ar', count=1500)

except TwythonError as e:
    print e

for tweet in search_results['statuses']:
    ['screen_name'].encode('utf-8'),tweet['created_at'])
    tweet_before_cleaning=tweet['text'].encode('utf-8'), '\n'
    search_results = re.sub(r"(?:\@|ftps?\://|https?\://)\S+", "",tweet_before_cleaning[0])
    search_results = re.sub(r"#","",search_results ).strip()
    search_results = re.sub(r"[a-zA-Z]+","",search_results ).strip()
    search_results = re.sub(r"[-\.:_.!?(){}\/]","",search_results ).strip()
    search_results = re.sub(r"\b","",search_results ).strip()
    print search_results
```

I can get the output on the required topic but with some special characters as ( ... or " " ) and some emojis.
I need to clean the output of such characters and emojis.
Is there a way in Python that can be implemented using my existing code that can remove them ?

Comment: The title made me laugh :P You probably want to use python to remove emoticons and characters, not emotions ^^

Comment: Hi @siscom - what code have you tried? Did you get any error messages?

Comment: search_results_ascii = search_results.encode('ascii')

Comment: the above line to get ascii representation of crawled data and then compare it with the range of arabic letter as emojis and charatcers will be out of range but got error : UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' code can't decode 0xd9 in position0 : ordinal not in range (128)

Comment: @Dylan ...you are right ..thanks for your note ..so can you help with a python code to remove ( emoticons ) :) ?

Comment: I added :  emoji_pattern = re.compile("["
        u"\U0001F600-\U0001F64F"  # emoticons
        u"\U0001F300-\U0001F5FF"  # symbols & pictographs
        u"\U0001F680-\U0001F6FF"  # transport & map symbols
        u"\U0001F1E0-\U0001F1FF"  # flags (iOS)
                           "]+", flags=re.UNICODE) 
then : 
 print(emoji_pattern.sub(r'', search_results))

Comment: this could remove the faces but this : rectangles containing letters  or " or ... characters

Comment: I am writing the code in english and I need the output in arabic
I need to remove some arabic characters in thw way they are written in arabic
for example I need to remove both (?) and (؟)

Comment: The problem is when I add (؟ )To the python code in a re.sub expression and run the python script ..I get the following message on the output file :[[[couldn't open the file using the unicode (UTF-8) character coding please check that you are not trying to open a binary file . Select a different character coding from the menu and try again ]]
changing the coding converts the output text to may be latin language or so .. how can I remove arabic ( ؟) and other arabic languages then ?